# Pytorch - is this the right way to load a big dataset using pytorch.data.Dataset and train it for Linear Regression

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch and currently working with a [historical weather dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tk1m2Yk0vevOPObKIbYotDWpK0V7r5nO/view?usp=sharing) and have built PyTorch DataLoader iterators and split the data to a train and test set successfully.

I want to run a simple Linear Regression model on this data to predict the column `["Temperature (C)"]`. I'm not doing any feature engineering and instead am just using all float point dtypes as features.

On running the model (just a fully connected layer with bias True - Linear Regression) , I see a decrease in loss in the first 2 batches or so and then the loss just fluctuates around `(100 +- 25)`. When I normalize the features, the loss decreases in the first batch but the fluctuation is around `200 +- 25`.

From what I've learnt, I know that once features are normalized SGD has a higher chance to converge faster. But there is a difference in the base loss ie. without feature normalization ~ *100*, with feature normalization/scaling ~ *200*.

**I feel that I've implemented something wrong somewhere but have not got any lines to figure out what I've messed up or whether this is even normal behavior.**

**[Update]**
This is how my **[loss function plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzJ5g.png)** looks through the descent. But I'm noticing that the variation of loss is too much. Am I wrong ? 
[Loss vs number of iterations plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzJ5g.png)
x-axis - number of iterations across 100 batch sizes; y-axis - Loss

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, random_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.optim import SGD

class LinearRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(LinearRegression, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.fc1(x)
        return output

class LoaderWeather(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, file_path, transform=None):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.transform = transform
        # self.scaler = StandardScaler()

        self.data = pd.read_csv(self.file_path)
        self.data = self.data.loc[:, self.data.dtypes == np.float64]

        self.outputs = self.data["Temperature (C)"]
        self.inputs = self.data.drop(["Apparent Temperature (C)", "Temperature (C)"], axis=1)

        self.outputs = np.array(self.outputs).reshape(-1,1)
        self.inputs = np.array(self.inputs)

        # self.inputs = self.scaler.fit_transform(np.array(self.inputs))

        #Normalize data
        # self.means = self.inputs.mean(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
        # self.stds = self.inputs.std(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
        # self.inputs = (self.inputs - self.means)/self.stds

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.inputs[idx], self.outputs[idx]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

def train_epoch(epoch, train_loader, regression_model, criterion, optimizer):

        print(epoch)
        train_loader = iter(train_loader)
        #Convert to tensors
        for iteration, (inputs, outputs) in enumerate(train_loader):
            # inputs,outputs = train_loader.next()


            inputs = Variable(torch.tensor(inputs).type(torch.FloatTensor))
            outputs = Variable(torch.tensor(outputs).type(torch.FloatTensor))

            #Clear the gradients w.r.t the parameters
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            #Forward pass
            predicted = regression_model(inputs) 

            #Calculate loss
            loss = criterion(predicted, outputs)

            #Backpropogate gradient of loss
            loss.backward()

            #Perform one step of gradient descent
            optimizer.step()

            #Verbosity
            if iteration % 100 == 0:
                print("epochs :{}, loss :{} , iteration: {},".format(epoch, loss, iteration))

        return regression_model, loss


def main():

 ############################################   
    #Hyper parameters
    batch_size=100
    n_iters = 20000
    learning_rate=0.0000001
#############################################

    weather_data = LoaderWeather("data/weatherHistory.csv")

    n = len(weather_data)
    n_train = int(0.8 * len(weather_data))
    n_test = n - n_train

    train, test = random_split(weather_data, lengths=[n_train, n_test])



    train_loader = DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=4)



    input_dim = 6
    output_dim = 1

    regression_model = LinearRegression(input_dim, output_dim)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()

    optimizer = SGD(regression_model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


    no_of_batches = np.floor(n/batch_size)

    print(no_of_batches)
    epochs = int(n_iters/no_of_batches)

    print("Total epochs : {}".format(epochs))

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        regression_model, loss = train_epoch(epoch, train_loader, regression_model, criterion, optimizer)


    print(regression_model, loss)   
    print(regression_model.parameters())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, please let me know if the way I'm doing my training is fine or something is fundamentally wrong here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to plot the  norm of the gradient  (with linear reg this shouldn't be too difficult). If the gradient is small, then the variance of the error is due to stochastic effects,whereas if the norm isn't small, there is probably some programming bug . Some common tricks to reduce the variance once convergence region is reached are to decay the learning rate (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/exponential_decay), or increase batch size. It all really depends on the level of accuracy you want to achieve.